# Add and Remove class property using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html/javascript code that has a basic structure like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div id="1" class="A">
    <ul>
    <li>...</li>
</li>
<li>
    <div id="2" class="A">
    <ul>
    <li>...</li>
</li>
<li>
    <div id="3" class="A">
    <ul>
    <li>...</li>
</li>
```

When you clicked on class A, a class will be appended to it's sibling ul, a sample is like this:

```
<li>
    <div id="1" class="A">
    <ul class="active">
    <li>...</li>
</li>
```

So, when you clicked on any class A, it will automatically append the **class Active** to the first ul instance.  When you clicked into all the **class A**, all ul will be appended by **class Active**.

Now, what I wanted to achieve is, when I clicked into a specific class A, ALL OTHER ul with class A will be **removed** with **class Active**.  And that **specific class A** will be the only one to GET the **class Active property**.

Is it possible?

Comment: [**jQuery Learning Center**](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Where does the `</div>` tag go?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.A').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To add active class to siblings, use,

```
$('div.A').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

**But** in your example, the `ul` is not exactly sibling, but children of the div.

```
$('div.A').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

or

```
$('div.A').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).children('ul').addClass('active');
});
```